# Interromper script sem encerrar o bat

Tags: php, batch

Um script PHP gera um arquivo `.bat` e em seguida executa o mesmo, o problema é que não quero que meu script PHP fique esperando tal `.bat` terminar de ser executado. Quero apenas que ele rode, crie e execute o bat e depois encerre sem esperar o bat terminar, como posso fazer isso? Já tentei adicionando `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` ao `exec` mas não funcionou.

Comment: Crie um outro bat que tenha a função de apenas iniciar o bat que demora. Exemplo: `start myBatch.bat`.

Comment: @LaércioLopes eu criei aqui um bat para iniciar o bat principal, e mesmo assim o PHP fica travado até que o bat termine de ser executado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se estiver no Windows, experimente utilizar:

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$WshShell->Run('%COMSPEC% /C '.$file, 0, false);
```

Se não quiser *confiar* no no `%COMSPEC%` especifique qual "*interpretador*" deseja, normalmente o `%WINDIR%\system32\cmd.exe` é o padrão e ele será utilizado.

---

### Teste isto:

> meu.bat

```
@ECHO off
TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
START %WINDIR%\system32\calc.exe
```

*Isso irá fazer esperar 5 segundos e depois abrir a calculadora (`%WINDIR%\system32\calc.exe`).*

> meu.php

```
<?php

$inicio = time();
$arquivo = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'meu.bat';

$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$WshShell->Run('%COMSPEC% /C '.$arquivo, 0, false);

$fim = time();

echo 'Finalizado em '.($fim - $inicio).' segundos';
```

### Resultado:

O PHP irá retornar o texto "Finalizado em 0 segundos", enquanto isto o CMD irá abrir a calculadora após 5 segundos.

O retorno do PHP é antes do termino da execução do CMD. ;)

Uma outra observação é que se o PHP estiver sendo executado "na mesma maquina do cliente" (*como em localhost*) nenhuma janela do CMD será mostrada ao usuário, assim permite executar qualquer comando de maneira silenciosa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**É necessário habilitar a extensão `php_com_dotnet.dll` no PHP.ini!**

Comment: ao terminar de executar o bat é possível rodar um script avisando que o processo acabou?

Comment: Uma vez que a página é enviada não. O que você pode fazer é chamar um um PHP, por exemplo `start c:\caminho\para\cli\php.exe outro.php` e esse arquivo ser responsável por notificar o usuário (via websockets) ou atualizar algo no banco de dados (ou arquivo de texto) e por ajax-polling encontrar que acabou. Uma outra opção seria de ir, em cada ajax-polling, vendo o `tasklist`, assim vendo se o processo encerrou ou não. Ao menos, é a única solução que vejo.